# From a pandas series of dates, match against a particular year

Tags: python, pandas, date

From a pandas Series of dates, which pandas Series method can I use to match against a particular year?

```py
import pandas as pd

date_series = pd.Series(["1 jan 2022", "2021-01-31", "19 dec 2016"])
print(date_series.**someMethod**("2021"))
```

The output I want is something like:

```
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

date_series = pd.Series(["1 jan 2022", "2021-01-31", "19 dec 2016"])
date_series = pd.to_datetime(date_series)
date_series.dt.year == 2021
>>
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```